# Call to firestore database returning undefined

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I am trying to retrieve an array from a document however the document is returning undefined in an asynchronous .then function

All other calls are working except for this one. The exact error code that is being received is

> Cannot read property 'email' of undefined at /srv/routes/raffles.js:54:37 at  at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)

Here is my relevant code:

````
  var array = await doc.data().email;

  await array.forEach(async function (value) {
      if (value == email) {
      } else {
          checkedScore++
      }
  });
});```

Doc returns as undefined even though I am not changing anything from my last requests. As you can see from my database, all names and paths are correct. http://prntscr.com/ogly3n
````

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
let document = await db.collection("raffles).doc("h5s3a").get();
let array= document.data().email;

        for (let element of array) {
            if (element == email){
              //do something
            }else{
              checkedScore++
            }
        }
```